# Datatable should show bottom scroll at screen bottom

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I have a data table with large number of columns and rows and when i increase the number of record than horizontal scroll goes to bottom.

but i want this to be at screen bottom so i can move it any time i need it.

Tried to fix it but nothing is working for me

if anyone can help me please help me with this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            responsive: true
        } );
    } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rikhi05/ebRXw/3265/

Comment: Do you mean within the current viewport?

Comment: this is working fine but not full bottom.
"scrollX": true

Comment: @sbm no not within viewport but screen, it shows horizontal scroll at datatables bottom and i want the same scroll at screen bottom if i move downside of screen.

Comment: @kamran added scrollX: true but it is not working as i want it

Comment: just increase the number of entries showing to 100 and horizontal scroll will move to datatable bottom and i want that scroll to screen bottom